# Updating src of video tag multiple times

Tags: html, video

On a simple page i have a list of titles, clicking on any title will dynamically update the src of a  element on the page. This works fine... a few times... then the browser (Safari) refuses to update the src any more, in the debugger it says something about failing to load local resource. If I how ever refresh the page, it will start working again, a few times until it stops again. It seems to work in all other browsers so I'm guessing it's a bug in Safari.

I simply update the src attribute of my video tag, and then call "load()" on the element.
I've also tried totally replacing the video element each time instead, but with the same result.

Any hints / workarounds?

Clarification: If I update the src with exactly the same source all the time will still exhibit the buggy behavior using Safari (v6.0.2). Replacing the src works a few times, then the browser suddenly stops accepting updates to the src and emits an error about not being able to load local resource.

**HTML part:**

```
<video controls>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="videos/myvideo.mp4"/>
</video>
<button id="#buttonChangeVideo">Change video</button>
```

**Javascript/jQuery part:**

```
$('#buttonChangeVideo').click(function() {
    var $video = $('video');
    $video.attr('src', 'videos/myvideo.mp4');
    $video.get(0).load();
});
```

Comment: Does it always fail on the same video? Is it possible that video doesn't exist anymore, is a bad format, or just doesn't load? I'd really have to see the page/code to debug further.

Comment: I've updated the original question with clarifications. It does not matter what video file I use or even if I try to load different videos.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I facing the same problem. The first time the page loads the video loads fast from cache. Every time the <video> tag is re-rendered less and less of the video is loaded until it crawls to a stop.

Comment: Nope, never got it to work on all platforms. My conclusion was that it's Safari that is buggy.

Answer (score 1):

```
<source type="text/html" src="videos/myvideo.mp4"/>

$video.attr('src', 'video/myvideo.mp4');
```

There is difference between **video** and **videos**

Comment: that was just a typo in my example here. Not in the actual code. I've updated the example.

Comment: It shouldn't be `type="video/mp4"`?

Comment: :) Too many typos here... The gist still is, it works a few times then stops working on Safari. works fine in other browsers.

Comment: Is this answer was satisfied? If yes please mark my answer as helpful.

Comment: No. It wasn't an answer to the question here.